# how can i find the greatest unique values like that table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

| COMPANY | ID | NUMBER | NAME | WORKING HOUR | WORKING PRICE | WORKING DAY | AUDIT PRICE | BONUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALASKA | 1 | 1232 | JOHN | 14,5 | 1102 | 23 | 1520 | 767 |
| NEWYORK | 1 | 1232 | JOHN | 1,5 | 114 | 7 | 375 | 0 |
| OHIO | 2 | 1414 | HARRY | 13,5 | 1020 | 25 | 1250 | 750 |
| ALASKA | 2 | 1414 | HARRY | 1,5 | 200 | 5 | 100 | 250 |

1. Choose `COMPANY` with the more working days
2. Group by `NUMBER` column
3. Addition (summation) of `WORKING HOUR`
4. Addition (summation) of `WORKING PRICE`
5. Addition (summation) of `WORKING DAY`
6. `AUDIT PRICE` choose the maximum number
7. BONUS price If one of these values ​​has a zero, write a zero. If it is not zero, I want to sum the values;

How can I do that in Google sheets using some formula? Please help

Like that table

| COMPANY | ID | NUMBER | NAME | WORKING HOUR | WORKING PRICE | WORKING DAY | AUDIT PRICE | BONUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALASKA | 1 | 1232 | JOHN | 16 | 1216 | 30 | 1520 | 0 |
| OHIO | 2 | 1414 | HARRY | 15 | 1220 | 30 | 1250 | 1000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(A1:I1;unique(tocol(B2:B;1));lambda(a;c;vstack(a;
        {+sort(filter({A:A\G:G};B:B=c);2;)\c\xlookup(c;B:B;C:D)\
        bycol(E:G;lambda(Σ;sumif(B:B;c;Σ)))\
        +sort(filter(H:H;B:B=c);1;)\
        let(Σ;filter(I:I;B:B=c);if(countif(Σ;0)>0;0;sum(Σ)))}
  )))
```

[image]